# cant understand why certain variable is being altered

Tags: assembly, masm, irvine32

I've been tasked with creating a program that will list composite numbers within a user identified range. To determine if a number is composite I will be dividing it and checking for a remainder of zero. My actual problem is trying to print the variable called "current" in my code. current is initialized to 3 and then incremented every loop, so I expect the number 4 to be printed first but 2 prints first. How is this possible, current never even gets to 2, it only increases from 3.

```
mov     ecx, terms
trial:
    inc     current
    mov     eax, current
    cdq
    mov     ebx, 2
    div     ebx
    cmp     edx, 0
    je      composite
    cmp     edx, 0
    jg      below


    composite:
        mov     edx, OFFSET current
        call    WriteDec
        call    CrLf

    below:
    loop    trial
```

If I input 9 I expect 4, 6 and 8 to print because these all leave a remainder of 0 when divided by 2. instead I get 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6 printed.

Comment: off-topic: `cdq` is the right setup for `idiv`, not `div`.  It *sign*-extends into EDX:EAX.  You want to zero-extend with `xor edx,edx`.  But really you want `shr eax,1` to do unsigned division by 2, not the very slow `div` instruction.  (And `test al,1` first to check the remainder, or look at CF which holds the bit shifted out).

Comment: @PeterCordes I knew about cdq and idiv but for some reason when I comment out the cdq my program crashes.

Comment: BTW, your algorithm is totally broken.  You're only ever dividing by 2, so you can't detect composite numbers like `9 = 3*3`, only even numbers (which are trivial and don't need a loop).  See [Checking if a number is prime in NASM Win64 Assembly](//codereview.stackexchange.com/q/204902) for a working trial-division loop.

Comment: It's not surprising your program crashed if you comment out `cdq` and don't replace it with `xor edx,edx`.  If EDX>1 before `div` by 2, then the quotient of `EDX:EAX / EBX` won't fit in EAX, so the CPU raises a `#DE` exception.  [When and why do we sign extend and use cdq with mul/div?](//stackoverflow.com/q/36464879)

Comment: @PeterCordes right now ive only implemented checking for even composite numbers, once I get that part working correctly I will account for the other composite numbers, do you know why current is not printing the way I expect it to?

Comment: @PeterCordes that makes perfect sense about the sign extending

Answer (score 0):

[WriteDec takes its arg in EAX](http://programming.msjc.edu/asm/help/source/irvinelib/writedec.htm).  It's printing that, not the pointer(!) that you put into EDX.  WriteDec takes an integer by value

When you call `WriteDec` the first time (on the first even number after 3), `EAX = 4/2 = 2`, so that's what you print.  Use a debugger to look at registers, you would have probably seen the `2` in EAX.

---

And BTW, your loop only checks for even numbers, not all composites.  (And you're doing it in a *massively* inefficient way.  Even is trivial, just `test al,1` to test the low bit of EAX.  This version is ready for us to expand to a trial-division loop after ruling out even numbers, but for now the simplest branching is just fall-through into print or not.

```
    mov     ecx, terms
    mov     ebx, current
trial:                  ; do {
    inc     ebx

    test     bl, 1
    jnz      odd           ; low bit set = not divisible by 2 = odd

    ;; TODO: trial division loop after ruling out even numbers
    ;; mov eax,ebx
    ;; xor edx,edx
    ;; div something  in a loop


    even:
        mov     eax, ebx    ; WriteDec takes an arg in EAX, and preserves all others
        call    WriteDec
        call    CrLf

    odd:
      cmp   ebx, ecx
      jb    trial       ; }while(current < terms)
      ;; The loop instruction is inefficient, don't bother with it
      ;; and you don't need a down-counter for the loop anyway
      ;; you already have terms

      mov    current, ebx    ; in case you care?
```

---

The simplest way to check for a composite is trial division: [Checking if a number is prime in NASM Win64 Assembly](//codereview.stackexchange.com/q/204902).

If you want to print all composites up to a certain number, it would be much more efficient to run a [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) to find odd composites up to a high enough value, then loop printing every even number, and odd numbers if their bitmap or bytemap entry is set in the sieve.